# How to add equation and R2 for a facetted plot in ggplot R2?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, lme4, mapply

The data has two factors. I ran a simple `lmer` for the model. I want to plot the data using facet_plot in ggplot. I want to display the equation and R2. Here is my attempt. I don't know to `facet` within the `lm_eqn` and then display correspond to the plots.

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(xaxis = rnorm(300, 2, 3), yaxis = rnorm(300,8,3), rfactor = rep(c("A","B","C"), times = 100), species = rep(c("AA","BB"), each = 150))

fit <- lmer(yaxis ~ xaxis + species + (1|rfactor), data= df)
summary(fit)

pred1 <- ggpredict(fit, c("xaxis", "species")) 
pred1 <- dplyr::rename(pred1, xaxis = x, species = group)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = xaxis, y = yaxis, color = species, group = species)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ species) +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = pred1,
    aes(x = xaxis, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, group = species),
    fill = "grey80", inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = .3
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = pred1,
    aes(x = xaxis, y = predicted, group = species),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

To add the equations + R2:

```
lm_eqn <- function(df){
  m <- lmer(yaxis ~ xaxis + species + (1|rfactor),  df);
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
                   list(a = format(unname(coef(m)[1]), digits = 2),
                        b = format(unname(coef(m)[2]), digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));
}

p + geom_text(x = 25, y = 300, label = lm_eqn(df), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your goal is.  You have a single `lmer` model that incorporates both species.  Do you want to show an equation for each level of the grouping factor (A,  B, C)? (That wouldn't be split across groups, so you would probably want to show it a single time, in black rather than in red/blue, to make it clear that it applied to both facets.) Or ... ? Maybe show a back-of-the-envelope sketch of what you want the results to look like?